# Not been able to change the SharePoint site URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, administration, site-template

I am trying to update the SharePoint site address but it is showing that the site address is unavailable, so I deleted that site and trying it again, and it is adding 2 in it **(siteadress2.com)**, showing there is an another site with original name but there are no such site available when I am checking it.

Can you guide me through the reason and what can I do ?

Thank You.

Comment: Hi @Gary_93, did you try my suggestion given below? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

After manually deleting the SharePoint site collection, the site collection will be available at Tenant Recycle bin but you won't be able to delete it manually.

You can use below PowerShell command to delete it permanently:

```
Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/sitetoremove
```

Check this thread for more information: [Reusing a Deleted SharePoint Site Name](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/reusing-a-deleted-sharepoint-site-name/m-p/201148)

**Documentation**: [Remove-SPODeletedSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-spodeletedsite?view=sharepoint-ps)